# Integration of Android Services and Receivers in Manifest in Codename One and how about iOS callbacks

Tags: android, ios, native, codenameone

I'm currently working on a feature which consists of playing alarm sounds at certain times even when the app is not running (also means that the service is working after device reboot without having to start the app). After each firing of an alarm the next alarm has to be scheduled (automatically) to a slightly differnet time. Thus [Local Notifications](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/local-notifications.html) are not an option here. This feature has to be supported on Android and iOS.

I want to implement the native android part at the moment but I don't know how to modify the application's manifest in order to register a custom [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and an [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html).

The next thing I'm curious about is, as I want to access CN1's [Storage](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/Storage.html) instance when I implement this feature for iOS, how to access that Storage instance in native iOS code. I checked [the post about native iOS callbacks](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/native-ios-code-callbacks.html) but I'm not sure if this also works for none-primitive parameter/return types on static methods.

Anyone knows the solution for both cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `android.xapplication` [build hint](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-theming.html) to inject the `BroadcastReceiver` & intent service XML.

Notice that if your syntax is incorrect you will get a build error and the manifest we generated will be listed within the error log for your inspection.

Storage on iOS is within the documents path:

```
NSArray *writablePaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [writablePaths lastObject];
```

It's stored under the `cn1storage` directory under the documents path. This is an implementation detail but it's unlikely to change in the future.